# What javascript array, nested array, object is most suitable for searching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a colors structure that has 3 data per item. For example, red has x and y, blue has x and y, etc. So the 3 pieces of data are `color, x, y`

What structure do I need to make it easy to read the x and y based on the color. I usually do `push(color, x, y)` but that wouldn't work here, because I need to search quickly by the color without needing to loop. What structure do I need here, and how do I set it and get it.

Comment: it would be better if you give example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var colors = [
  {color: 'blue',  x: 897, y: 98 },
  {color: 'red', x: 25,  y: 1334 },
  {color: 'yellow', x: 50, y: 12 }
]

for(var i in colors) {
  console.log(colors[i].color);
  console.log(colors[i].x);
  console.log(colors[i].y);
}
// To insert into colors

colors.push({color: 'pink', x: 150, y: 200});
```

or if you have structure like this

```
var colors = [
   ['red', 837, 98], 
   ['blue', 25, 144], 
   ['yellow', 50, 12]
];
```

then

```
for(var i in colors) {
  console.log(colors[i][0]); // output: red, yellow ...
  console.log(colors[i][1]); // output: 837, 25 ..
  console.log(colors[i][2]); // output: 98, 144 ..
}

and to insert into colors for this structure
colors.push(['pink', 150, 200])
```

or

```
var colors = {
  blue: { x: 58, y: 100 },
  red: { x: 43, y: 1334 },
  yellow: {x: 254, y: 12 }
}
```

then

```
for(var i in colors) {
  console.log(colors[i].blue.x);
  console.log(colors[i].blue.y);
  // or
  console.log(colors[i]['blue'].x);
  // or like
  console.log(colors[i]['blue']['x']);
}

// and to insert for this sturcture

colors.pink= {x: 150, y: 200};
```

Answer (score 4):

What about a simple object (hash) ?

```
// Initial creation
var colors = {
  blue: { x: 897, y: 98 },
  red: { x: 43, y: 1334 },
  yellow: { y: 12 }
}

// Adding new element to existing object
colors['green'] = { x: 19 };

// Accessing them
console.log(colors.blue.x);
console.log(colors.yellow.y);

// Accessing them with name in var
var needed = 'green';
console.log(colors[needed].x);
console.log(colors[needed]['x']);
```

Or did I understand you wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like a dictionary?!?

```
var colorArray = {};
colorArray["red"] = {
    x: 100,
    y: 200
};
colorArray["blue"] = {
    x: 222,
    y: 200
};
alert(colorArray["red"].x);​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var colors = {
    red  : { x : 42, y : 7 },
    blue : { x : .., y : .. },
    ...
};

alert(colors.red.x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you need the color also in the array

```
var colors = {
 blue: { color:"blue", x: 100, y: 200 },
 red: { color:"red", x: 50, y: 300 },
 yellow: { color:"yellow", x: 30 y: 700 }
}
```

You also could use string "constants":

```
var RED = "red";

var colors = {};
 colors[RED] = { color: RED, x: 100, y: 200 };
 ...
```